# Self-deletion and un-deletion without any changes should reinstate the original close/delete votes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete, undelete

Currently, when a user self-deletes a post and subsequently undeletes it, any votes to delete or votes to close magically disappear as if they never happened. While that might make some sense if a user deleted a post to then significantly update it, it seems to make no sense in the case where nothing changed.

I would propose that if nothing happened between the delete and undelete events, the original votes on the post are reinstated.

Comment: I would propose that *regardless* of what happens between the delete and undelete, the original votes are reinstated.

Comment: I'm unaware of the full possible chain of events between a delete and undelete @DuncanJones. So perhaps it doesn't always make sense to do so. But I'm sure someone will have a look at that.

Comment: Not usually a problem, @Duncan, as the OP can't edit a self-deleted question.

Comment: Do we have any numbers on how many votes are being vanished this way? The change seems sensible, but I'm curious as to whether this is actually happening in the wild.

Comment: @blahdiblah don't know how often, but the question was inspired by such an event happening today.

Comment: Wait: you can't edit a deleted post? I did that several times (ohh, my answer is wrong, remove it, correct it, undelete)

Comment: Not for questions @JohannesKuhn.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Implemented in build `2014.1.23.1883` on meta and `2014.1.23.1324` on sites.

An delete undelete sequence on a post by the post owner will invalidate only the owner's delete vote when the undeletion is made.

Comment: Super! Well, that must be the quickest/most successful bounty in history. I'll award after time limit has passed.

Comment: Thanks for that and also, congrats for a new Nice Answer Badge :D

Answer (score -6):

I agree with the point made that if no edits were done, then the original votes stay.  I also think that ***we should retract the delete votes if it has been edited, so the original deleters can re-cast their vote***.

Comment: I disagree with your last statement.

Comment: Though perhaps something could be said for a very gradual expiry of delete votes in that case @GeorgeStocker? (Though that would be another topic entirely of course)

Comment: Delete votes should (a) be preserved and (b) be retractable (not currently possible).  That's similar to close/retract/reopen -- let the *voters* decide, not the *system*.  Somebody shouldn't be able to flush delete votes against his post with a one-character change.