# Allow me to close vote deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

Currently, when a question is deleted - it is no longer possible to close vote it.

However, users can delete and then undelete their own questions at will.

This means, that even if users want to close vote a bad question they've seen they now can't (there is a "this question is now deleted" dialog) and OP is free to reopen it.

#### I suggest letting users to close-vote deleted questions that were deleted by the original poster.

This seems like a sensible thing to me and I was quite surprised when it didn't work. I've run into a few questions before that got deleted (so I couldn't close vote them) only to find them just as bad and undeleted a day later (at which point I CV'd them).

(This would probably only work to users with 10K since users with less reputation can not see deleted questions anyway)

([most related question I've found - I've been looking for the past 15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203807/self-deletion-and-un-deletion-without-any-changes-should-reinstate-the-original))

Comment: As an aside, currently you *can* reopen a question while it's still deleted...

Comment: @animuson interesting, I didn't know that - do you happen to know the reasoning?

Comment: I personally have no idea - I just know it works.

Comment: @animuson Do you happen to know the reasoning behind that now, as you are now a staff member (or dev)?

Answer (score 2):

I think that if an question were deleted by the OP then closing it would be a little bit of overkill. However, you do make a good case for avoiding exploitation. If a savvy user were to delete their post to avoid close votes then this would bypass that.

One thing to consider though. This could cause bugs in the review system. At present I would assume that it skips deleted posts. Perhaps, if enabled, this should only be allowed if a user (10k+ as stated) navigates directly to the page.

Comment: You can't close answers... :)

Comment: I'm only asking to be able to close them explicitly - I don't mind if they skip the queue entirely.