# The wording of "this question is now deleted" is misleading and should be changed

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, deleted-questions, wording

If you try to close a question that is already deleted, you get the following popup message:

> This question is now deleted

[image: Screenshot showing popup message]

This sounds like it means one of two things:

1. The action you just took has caused this question to be deleted.
2. The question was not deleted when you opened it, but by the time you cast the close vote, it had been deleted.

In reality, what it means to say is simply that the question is deleted (and therefore can't be closed). So, can it be changed to just say that, or perhaps even better, to say that it *can't be closed* because it is deleted?

Comment: Worse, it that it lets you go through the closing dialog, and choose a reason, before bailing out at the last moment, but that was already reported, this result (above) was the *fix*: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185913/282094 - yet the antipode is possible reopening a deleted question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190443/282094 leaves it deleted. --- Duplicate (but not about the wording): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212242/282094

Comment: @Rob I was actually going to ask why some blocks on close-voting don't show up until you complete the process, while others (lacking an accepted or positive answer for duplicates) stop you as soon as you try to select the other question.

Comment: The close dialog (duplicate section) ***should*** sort suggested duplicates by *better* choices, see: "[Improve tools for closing as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77103/282094)". **Usually** you are blocked from selecting seemingly ***bad*** duplicates but that doesn't apply if you choose the OP's prior question, ... [continued]

Comment: [continued comment]  on meta there are **no** restrictions on *what* is a duplicate (it's actually helpful to choose similar, opposite, and not so close *duplicates* ***because*** up to **5** can be held in the banner, see: "[Changes to “close as duplicate” (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/282094)"). Dupes with **no** answers, while unhelpful, are OK on MSE.-- But [your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359952/the-wording-of-this-question-is-now-deleted-is-misleading-and-should-be-change?noredirect=1#comment1201247_359952) is a new question, and a duplicate.